# loads specific url's & clicks a button automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to javascript & i want to do this simple thing.

I want to make a script which goes to coded url's & clicks on a button each time the script is executed.

Suppose,i have these [links](https://facebook.com/user1,https://facebook.com/user2) -
I want the javascript to to go on these links after running it & trigger another small js for both links after they are fully loaded.

Here's what i tried

```
    var linkArray = ('https://facebook.com/user1','https://facebook.com/user2');
for (var i = 0; i < linkArray.length; i++) { window.open({
url: linkArray[i]
});
}
linkArray.onload="blabla();"

function blabla()
{
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('_42ft _4jy0 _63_s _4jy4 _517h _51sy');for(var i=1; i<inputs.length;i++) {inputs[i].click();}
}
```

Can anyone please help?
Thanks in advance! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Please change to this, this would works

```
var linkarray = ('https://facebook.com/user1', 'https://facebook.com/user2');
```

Comment: Wrong!

Try to do `console.log(linkarray)` and you'll only get **'https://facebook.com/user2'**
So the best way to initialize the array is using ['any_content']

Comment: Can you please give a script demo on this regards?

Answer (score -1):

```
var linkArray = [https://facebook.com/user1,https://facebook.com/user2];
```

isn't valid, please set your array like this:

```
var linkArray = ['https://facebook.com/user1', 'https://facebook.com/user2'];
```